# What does $[n=0]$ mean?

Tags: notation, recurrence-relations

Namely, in the context of a recursively defined sequence:

$a_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+[n=0]$

where b is an element of another sequence.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without context, but I would guess it's $1$ if $n=0$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: It means here "add 0 or 1" according to the case where "n=0" is a false or true proposition resp. (a boolean converted into a numerical value)

Comment: It’s an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), and both of the earlier comments interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It’s an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), and both of the earlier comments interpret it correctly.